# ConfigurationBuilder does not override node when adding another json fill

Tags: c#

The code looks like this:

```
private static FooTestConfiguration LoadConfiguration()
{
    IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", true)
        .AddJsonFile("appSettings.local.json", true)
        .AddJsonFile(RetrieveProdSettingPath(), true)
        .Build();

    FooTestConfiguration result = config.Get<FooTestConfiguration>();
    result.ValidateAndSetDefaults();

    return result;
}
```

My `appSettings.local.json` like:

```
{
  "foo": "C:\\test\\test.exe",
  "KillOption": "DontKillWithInVisualStudio",
  "AttachmentPath": "X:\\foo\\Testautomation",
  "Variations": [
    {
      "Resolution": "FullScreen",
      "UseBar": true
    },
    {
      "Resolution": "FullScreen",
      "UseBar": false
    }
  ]
}
```

My prod-settings:

```
{
  "Variations": [
    {
      "Resolution": "FullScreen",
      "UseBar": true
    }
  ]
}
```

When building it, there are still two variations, but I would only like to have the prod variation. If I comment out the `.AddJsonFile("appSettings.local.json", true)`, the built config is correct.

Is there any way completely override / replace the Variations node completely?

Comment: I just ran into this issue too, so I'm still investigating. I think it's because internally, the configurations don't see lists as special objects by default. You can debug and see that list entries have children with `:0`, `:1`, etc. So to us, setting something to be a new list, isn't really a list, it just overrides the elements that are already in the lists at those positions and doesn't remove elements after. Maybe adding `null` or dummy entries to the list for prod will help?

Answer (score 3):

appsettings.json should be the 'default', and appsettings.local.json is used to override the defaults when running locally.

Make the .local file optional, and then don't deploy it to production.

```
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: false) <-- required, contains default settings
    .AddJsonFile("appSettings.local.json", optional: true) <--- only used when running locally
    .AddJsonFile(RetrieveProdSettingPath(), true)
    .Build();
```

You really should look at overriding both of these settings files, in a production environment, with environment variables.  This means that you can override the UAT and PROD environments during deployment, without any changes to any appsettings files.  This would replace your `RetrieveProdSettingPath` call.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. The second argument is actually: "false" = required and "true" = optional, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, required, optional, optional doesn't do have any affect. The local-settings still aren't replaced.

Comment: They shouldn't be 'replaced', local should never be loaded, because the file not there !